# How to set the menu of a Toolbar inside a Fragment

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have a simple layout with one main `Activity`, a `ViewPager` and a `BottomNavigationView` with 4 buttons. Tapping on each button simply changes the current item on the ViewPager, which loads the correct `Fragment`.

Each fragment has their own `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, and my goal is for each one to show different menu items on the Toolbar. I've tried several approaches but haven't been able to make any menu items show up in the Toolbar. This is my code:

**Fragment.java**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Fragment title");

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visible="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

The Activity itself has no menu-related code. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: The `Toolbar`, as opposed to the old `Menu`  is a ViewGroup in itself. so why don't you just programmatically add views to the toolbar in the `onCreateView()` of each of your fragments?

Comment: For example, after obtaining the `toolbar` object, you may add a child view using `addView(childView)` or `setTitle(title)`

Comment: Indeed - Just realized a much simpler solution is by calling toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu) directly.

Comment: I Suggest you to use One toolbar in Activity and change the menu of that toolbar according to need in fragment, just like whatsApp, you can hide the menu option on Your onCreateOptionsMenu or you can Apply the new Menu here.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getactivity().findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the lines

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in the fragment's `onActivityCreated`